# Make div only as long as parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an area where users can searc:

```
    <div id="questions-container">
<div>
   <div id="searchbar-region">
      <div>
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <input id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" value="" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="categories-region">
      <div>
         <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="default-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
               <span id="category" class="pull-left">Toutes catégories</span>
               <div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div>
            </button>
            <ul id="categories" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
               <li><a href="#" class="category" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                  Toutes catégories
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="items-region" class="left-panel-items">
      <div>
         <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">
            <div class="btn btn-default">
               <div class="text-left">
                  À quand remonte votre dernier examen medical?
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn btn-default">
               <div class="text-left">
                  Avez vous des démangeaisons?
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The idea is, I have a div and inside is:

```
A search bar.
A category dropdown.
a list of questions.
```

Normally this div which contains these things has a height proportional to the window height because it reaches the bottom of the page.

So if I only have a few questions, the div's height does not change.

If I have lots of questions, I easily find the div's height to be 4,000px.

This causes the div itself to have an overflow instead of the items-region. The items-region should not go any furthur such that the parent div never has to get bigger.

All this to say, I want the items-region div to correctly overflow. I do not want its parent to get bigger and overflow instead because then I end up scrolling the search bar out of sight.

Comment: your css that you added ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the parent a height, and also give the child a max-height equal to less than the parent height (and any child padding).

```
<div style="height: 400px;">
  <div style="max-height: 390px; overflow-y:auto;">
    <div style="height: 5000px; background:red">Simulated long block</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the both the child and parent block will only take up 400px and will be scrollable if the content inside it exceeds 390px.

Like this: http://codepen.io/ovdojoey/pen/WvqQNm

Comment: The parent's height changes when the window's height changes so I cannot set a fixed height on the parent, I just do not want the child to cause it to grow.

Comment: If the parent height changes when the window height changes, you still need to use max-height then, but you can use vh units which are measurements based on the viewport... set the child max-height: 100% as long as the parent height is defined explicitly either as vh, or a length in pixels.